# Parsing double-character command using getopt() C

Tags: c, getopt

Is there a way to make getopt() or getopt_long() recognise double character option?

example: `./a.out -my argument` where my is single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getopt_long_only`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt), which will try to process options as long ones even if there is only one `-` sign before them.

This function is GNU extension, as well as `getopt_long`.